# Populate table based on selected dropdown value

Tags: php, html-table, dropdown

I want to know where to put the condition to display data in a table after I select the value from a dropdown list.

Both have the same id (dropdown and table).

> php table

```
<html>    
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","company");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $sql="SELECT employees.id,employees.jobs FROM employees WHERE employees.jobs in ("programmer","hr","qa")";
    if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        ?>
        <label for="y">Select the job:</label>
        <select name="loads" id="loads" onchange=""> 
        <?php while($ri = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $ri['id'];?>" >  <?php echo $ri['jobs']; ?> </option>
            <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
    </select> 
    <table class="striped" border="1" align="center" id="demo">
        <tr class="header">
            <td align="center"><b>Name</b></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","company");
        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
        $sql2="SELECT employees.id,employees.name FROM employees WHERE employees.jobs in ("programmer","hr","qa")";

        if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql2)){
            // Fetch one and one row
            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row["name"] . " " . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }

        mysqli_close($con);
        ?>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean: you want to something happens to your table when an item get selected in dropdown list(select tag). then it is not possible through php because php codes compiled once after each load on a page and it doesnt work live!
so you have to use JQUERY and AJAX to do that.

if this is what you searching for, reply me so i can help you.

by the way you dont need to connect 2 times into database and run the same query, i just edited your code a little bit:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","company");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $sql="SELECT * FROM employees WHERE employees.jobs in ("programmer","hr","qa")";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if ($result) { ?>

        <label for="y">Select the job:</label>
        <select name="loads" id="loads" onchange="">
        <?php while($ri = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $ri['id'];?>" >  <?php echo $ri['jobs']; ?> </option>
            <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    <table class="striped" border="1" align="center" id="demo">
    <tr class="header">
        <td align="center"><b>Name</b></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    // Fetch one and one row
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["name"] . " " . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```